# how to create session name dynamically while running a workflow

Tags: unix, informatica

I have created a single mapping, session and workflow to load different tables which have the same data structure. I created a shell script to create a parameter file dynamically and run workflow based on tables. Now the issue is that when I run this workflow all session names are same as I created only one session but tables are different. I need the session names to be different and I should get like *(session_name_table_name)*.

Please help me to solve this issue. sorry for my bad English if not able to understand.

Comment: I did not quite understand. You are using a single workflow and session. So how can the session names be different? Do you mean session log name?

Comment: We have a requirement , to use a single session(In session properties will keep the DB name as dynamic) within a workflow and feed it with source and target table name through parameter file.Now my requirement is to create one workflow entry in monitor with session statistics /run properties on table level.

Comment: I think it is not possible to have a single workflow entry with multiple session entry in workflow monitor. But you can have different workflow names based on table name.

Comment: Okay Please let me know how to do in workflow level @Samik.   still leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the `pmcmd`command pass the option `-rin <run instance>`. `<run instance>` should be replaced with your table name.

In the workflow monitor, the run instance name would appear in [ ] beside the workflow. Ex. wkf_s_m_load_test [T_TEST1]